# local global variable issue - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables, local-variables

In the js GetTotal() function I have a confirm box followed by an IF statement which either (1) calculates the new total (if the user chooses 'ok'); or (2) reloads variables 'input1' and 'input2' into the text input boxes (if the user chooses 'cancel'). When 'input1' and 'input2' are reloaded they always reset to the original global values for 'input1' (5555) and 'input2' (666) even if the user has changed these variables previously.

I would like to have the values for 'input1' and 'input2' reloaded with the most recently entered variables (which will be consistent with the total displayed) rather than always reverting to the original global values for 'input1' (5555) and 'input2' (666). I reckon this is something to do with local and global but I can't figure it out. V grateful for any advice. Mike.

```
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.35.1/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>

<script>

var input1 = 5555;
var input2 = 666;

$(document).ready(function() {
  document.getElementById("input1").value = input1;
  document.getElementById("input2").value = input2;
  GetFirstTotal();  
});




function GetFirstTotal() {
    var total = 0;
    $('input[type=text]').each(function(index, value) {
      total += parseInt($(value).val() || 0);
    });

    $("#chkTotal").html(total);
}

function GetTotal() {
total = 0
  BootstrapDialog.confirm('Are you sure you want to do this?', function(result){
   if(result) {
         $('input[type=text]').each(function(index, value) {
             total += parseInt($(value).val() || 0);
         });
         $("#chkTotal").html(total);
   }else{document.getElementById("input1").value = input1;
  document.getElementById("input2").value = input2;}
});
}

</script>

TOTAL:
<div id="chkTotal"></div>
<br>
<input type="text" name="input1" id="input1"/>
<input type="button" value="Change X" onclick="GetTotal(this)"/>
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" name="input2" id="input2"/>
<input type="button" value="Change Y" onclick="GetTotal(this)"/>
```

Comment: Not entirely clear what you mean by *"When 'input1' and 'input2' are reloaded"*. Do you mean when the page is refreshed? Because that's normal, as it's reloading the script too, and doesn't know about what happened before you refreshed the page...

Comment: If the end user opts for 'cancel' at the confirm box the ELSE statement repopulates the form inputs with variables 'input1' and 'input2'. In this case the values for input1 and input2 which appear are always the original values declared at the start of the javascript segment of the code (i.e. 'input1' = 5555 and 'input2' = 666). When the form is repopulated I'd like the most recent values for 'input1' and 'input2' to be used instead of the original values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all you need to do is set `input1` and `input2` to the value of their corresponding textboxes in `GetTotal`:

```
function GetTotal() {
  total = 0
  BootstrapDialog.confirm('Are you sure you want to do this?', function(result){
  if(result) {
    input1 = parseInt($('#input1').val() || 0, 10);
    input2 = parseInt($('#input2').val() || 0, 10);
    // note that since you only have two fields, it's just as easy to write
    total = input1 + input2;
    //$('input[type=text]').each(function(index, value) {
    //    total += parseInt($(value).val() || 0);
    //});
    $("#chkTotal").html(total);
  }else{
    document.getElementById("input1").value = input1;
    document.getElementById("input2").value = input2;
  }
});
```

Comment: Note that I used `parseInt(value, radix)`, using 10 as the radix. It's not strictly necessary, but if a user entered "010", they would not get 10 in some earlier versions of JavaScript, due to "0" indicating octal.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your variables when the end-user enters in a value. Something  to the effect of this might work:

```
$('#input1').on('change blur', function() {
    input1 = Number(this.value);
});
```